# Python SMTP: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 7: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

**My all code :`**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


smtp_adresi="smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port=587
user="****@gmail.com"
pass="*****"


gonderilecek_adresler=["****@bilalkocak.net","******@gmail.com"]
konu="Subject"
content="HTML content"



mail=MIMEText(content,"html","UTF-8")

mail["From"]=kullanıcı_adı

mail["Subject"]=konu

mail["To"]=",".join(gonderilecek_adresler)

mail=mail.as_string()


s=smtplib.SMTP(smtp_adresi,smtp_port)

s.starttls()

s.login(user,pass)

s.sendmail(user,gonderilecek_adresler,mail)
```

**Result:**

> C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   "C:/Users/ASUS/PycharmProjects/Again/SMTP ile Mail/main.py" 'utf-8'
>   codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 7: invalid continuation byte
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: `"utf - 8"` why the spaces are needed? Try without them `"utf-8"`

Comment: I tried, but the result is the same

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` insert this in your first line.

Comment: unfortunately it has not changed

Comment: `\xe7` is the `ç` in your name but not encoded in UTF-8 (maybe cp1254, Turkish name?).  Save your source file in UTF-8 and try again.  It helps to have a reproducible example.  Your `******` in the source probably removed the problem.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\xe7 is the ç in your name but not encoded in UTF-8 (maybe cp1254, Turkish name?). Save your source file in UTF-8 and try again. It helps to have a reproducible example. Your ****** in the source probably removed the problem.

Note `#coding:utf8` at the top of the file declares the encoding of the file, but it is the default in Python 3 so it is not required.  Python 2 would need it.